# How do I create a document with subdocument in MongoDB with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to create a nested document with c# in mongodb.
My Code Looks like this

```
var documnt = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "name","test1"},
                { "nachname","test5"},
                { "age","test2"},
                { "wohnort","test3"},
                {"test","test4" }

            };
            collection.InsertOneAsync(documnt);
            Console.Read();`
```

how can i add a subdocument to Wohnort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found the answer by myself

```
var documnt = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "name","test1"},
            { "nachname","test5"},
            { "age","test2"},
            { "wohnort", new BsonArray
            {
               new BsonDocument {{"test1","test1"}}}
            }
        };
        collection.InsertMany(documnt);
        Console.Read();
```